# Python: Parsing logical string into list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I get string of logical expressions from a database and need to put these into a list of lists for further evaluation. I already tried reading a lot about string parsing but could not find the answer so far. For easier understanding of the problem, here are 3 examples:

```
input_string1 = '((A OR B) AND (C OR D)) OR E'
input_string2 = '(A AND ( B OR C ) AND D AND E)'
input_string3 = ' A OR ( B AND C ) OR D OR E'
```

expected ouput:

```
Results_string1=[ ['A', 'C'], ['A','D'], ['B','C'], ['B','D'], ['E']]
Results_string2=[ ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E'] ]
Results_string3=[ ['A'], ['B','C'], ['D'], ['E'] ]
```

So basically I need the fully factorized expressions in terms of `OR` and put those into the list. This means any `AND` condition is expressed by having both expressions in the same `sublist`, while any `OR` condition triggers the creation of new sublists.

```
e.g. E AND F --> [E, F], E OR F --> [[E],[F]]
```

The strings from the database have arbitrary length and an arbitrary amount of brackets.

Anyone got an idea how to define the grammar, such that I can use e.g. the pyparsing package?

The start of the grammar so far is:

```
import pyparsing as pp
gene_id = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
logical = ( pp.Keyword("AND") | pp.Keyword("OR") ).setName("logical")
l_brackets = (pp.Literal('(') ).setName('l_brackets')
r_brackets = ( pp.Literal(')') ).setName('r_brackets')
```

But how do I have to define the real parser?

One of the main problems is that I don't know how to handle the arbitrary occurring brackets and varying length of the string. I've been playing around with the `nestedExpr()-parser` from the `pyparser` toolbox but could not create the correct behavior so far.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @tobias_k Or he could use `+` or `*` if he's willing to go for the symbols used in Discrete Mathematics.

Comment: So, he is just supposed to simplify the expression. I'm thinking of looping through the expression with a behavior of a lexical analyzer (?).

Comment: Look at the SimpleBool.py example at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that gives the result you desire using a tokenizer and recursive descent parser. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the `pyparsing` library so I did not use it.

```
s1 = '((A OR B) AND (C OR D)) OR E'
s2 = '(A AND ( B OR C ) AND D AND E)'
s3 = ' A OR ( B AND C ) OR D OR E'

class Token:
    def __init__(self, name, value, location):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.location = location

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

def tokenize(s):
    index = 0
    tokens = []
    while index < len(s):
        c = s[index]

        if c == '(':
            tokens.append(Token('LPAREN', '(', index))
            index += 1
            continue
        elif c == ')':
            tokens.append(Token('RPAREN', ')', index))
            index += 1
            continue
        elif s[index:index+2] == 'OR':
            tokens.append(Token('OR', 'OR', index))
            index += 2
            continue
        elif s[index:index+3] == 'AND':
            tokens.append(Token('AND', 'AND', index))
            index += 3
            continue
        else:
            start = index
            while index < len(s) and s[index].isalpha(): 
                index += 1
            if not start == index:
                tokens.append(Token('SYMBOL', s[start:index], start))
            else:
                index += 1

    return tokens

def eval_and(left, right):
    result = []
    for l in left:
        for r in right:
            result.append(l+r)

    return result 

def eval_or(left, right):
    left.extend(right)
    return left

def parse_symbol(tokens, index):
    token = tokens[index]
    if token.name == 'SYMBOL':
        return ([[token.value]], index+1)
    else:
        raise

def parse_paren(tokens, index):
    lparen = tokens[index]
    index += 1
    if not lparen.name == 'LPAREN':
        raise

    result, index = parse_expr(tokens, index)

    rparen = tokens[index]
    index += 1
    if not rparen.name == 'RPAREN':
        raise

    return (result, index)

def parse_expr(tokens, index):
    left = None
    right = None

    token = tokens[index]
    if token.name == 'LPAREN':
        left, index = parse_paren(tokens, index)
    elif token.name == 'SYMBOL':
        left, index = parse_symbol(tokens, index)

    op = tokens[index]
    index += 1
    if not op.name == 'OR' and not op.name == 'AND':
        raise

    while True:
        token = tokens[index]
        if token.name == 'LPAREN':
            right, index = parse_paren(tokens, index)
        elif token.name == 'SYMBOL':
            right, index = parse_symbol(tokens, index)

        op = eval_or if op.name == 'OR' else eval_and
        result = op(left, right)

        continue_ = False
        if not index == len(tokens):
            next_ = tokens[index]
            if next_.name == 'OR' or next_.name == 'AND':
                continue_ = True
                op = next_

        if continue_:
            left = result
            index += 1
            continue
        else:
            return (result, index)

def parse(tokens):
    result = None

    token = tokens[0]
    if token.name == 'LPAREN':
        result, _ = parse_paren(tokens, 0)
    else:
        result, _ = parse_expr(tokens, 0)

    return result

for s in [s1, s2, s3]:
    print parse(tokenize(s))
```

The output is

```
[['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D']]
[['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D'], ['E']]
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much. This is exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the recursive nature of the expression, you can use the `Forward` element, and for the variable length clauses you can use `ZeroOrMore`. Based on your existing grammar:

```
expression = pp.Forward()
atom = gene_id | pp.Group(l_brackets + expression + r_brackets)
expression << atom + pp.ZeroOrMore(logical + expression)
```

With this, `expression.parseString` results in the following for your input strings:

```
[['(', ['(', 'A', 'OR', 'B', ')'], 'AND', ['(', 'C', 'OR', 'D', ')'], ')'], 'OR', 'E']
[['(', 'A', 'AND', ['(', 'B', 'OR', 'C', ')'], 'AND', 'D', 'AND', 'E', ')']]
['A', 'OR', ['(', 'B', 'AND', 'C', ')'], 'OR', 'D', 'OR', 'E']
```

If you want to get rid of the `(` and `)` in the output, you should call `suppress()` on `l_bracket` and `r_bracket`. Given the grouping (with `Group`) those are not really needed. Output will then be, e.g., `[['A', 'AND', ['B', 'OR', 'C'], 'AND', 'D', 'AND', 'E']]` for your second string.

The [conversion to DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_to_DNF) is another matter and should best be asked in another question.

Comment: thank you very much, this looks really great and I'll be trying this as soon as i can! with this output, it should be easy to create the lists I'm looking for.

Comment: Read up on pyparsing's [`infixNotation`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#infixNotation) method to help you handle proper precedence of operations. Also see the [simpleBool.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py/451074414/simpleBool.py) example at the pyparsing wiki.